# Long permalinks get split with multidots and get broken

Tags: permalinks

I have pages which are nested in 3 levels, i.e:

```
www.example.com/cinema-in-our-country/our-festivals/first-festival-with-very-long-name
```

As you can see the permalink gets quite long. If I go to the TinyMCE editor, write festival name and try to add a link on it to direct to that festival page, I get such generated link (notice three dots):

```
www.example.com/cinema-in-our-country/our-festivals/first-f...l-with-very-long-name
```

And the link does not work, it directs to 404 page. If I update the link with the correct, it saves well.

Actually I cannot repeat this behavior all the time. Sometimes this works just fine from the beggining. Any ideas what can couse this?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off all plugins, switch to TwentyTen [or - even better - this theme](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme). Then add another post with an ridiculously long title

```
Lopado­temacho­selacho­galeo­kranio­leipsano­drim­hypo­trimmato­silphio­parao­melito­katakechy­meno­kichl­epi­kossypho­phatto­perister­alektryon­opte­kephallio­kigklo­peleio­lagoio­siraio­baphe­tragano­pterygon
```

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lopado%C2%ADtemacho%C2%ADselacho%C2%ADgaleo%C2%ADkranio%C2%ADleipsano%C2%ADdrim%C2%ADhypo%C2%ADtrimmato%C2%ADsilphio%C2%ADparao%C2%ADmelito%C2%ADkatakechy%C2%ADmeno%C2%ADkichl%C2%ADepi%C2%ADkossypho%C2%ADphatto%C2%ADperister%C2%ADalektryon%C2%ADopte%C2%ADkephallio%C2%ADkigklo%C2%ADpeleio%C2%ADlagoio%C2%ADsiraio%C2%ADbaphe%C2%ADtragano%C2%ADpterygon)</sup>

Then see if it works now. If it doesn't: Re-install WP from the Admin > Dashboard/Updates page. If it does work, activate one plugin and retry, then the next one and so on. As a last step activate your theme again. This way you're able to trac down what exact piece of software is causing the problem. Then update your question with a link to its source (if it's freely available).

Answer (score 0):

The dots aren't part of the link - they just mean that the link it too long to fit in the space, and so part of the link URL has been hidden to make it fit. The acutal link is unchanged and will not contain these dots, though.

Use the <kbd>View post</kbd> button to open your post instead of copying the link.

Comment: I wish you were right, but the wrong link gets saved into database. Here is what I get when I see link on frontend:

http://i48.tinypic.com/egoa5d.jpg